# C++ CLR unmanaged BYTE* to managed System::array<Byte>^ without loop

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, type-conversion, clr

I tried to find working solution on my qestion, but not found.
I want to "connect" managed C# .NET code with native C++ code (DLL). My C++ returns unmanaged BYTE* pointer and count of elements.
How to initialize new `array<Byte>^` from `BYTE*` without loop? Because it may be to 5 Megabytes. (Encrypting data)
Help if you can please.

**EDIT:**

With loop it works:

```
    array<Byte>^ a = gcnew array<Byte>(resultDataSize);
    for (int i = 0; i < resultDataSize; i++)
    {
        a[i] = resultData[i];
    }
```

But I'd like get something like:

```
a = new array<Byte>(resultData, resultDataSize);
```

**EDIT 2:**

Now in my C++ i have function:

```
void Decrypt(BYTE* dataToDecrypt, DWORD dataToDecryptLength, wchar_t* senderName, wchar_t* receiverName, BYTE** result, DWORD* resultSize)
{
...
*result = main.Data;
*resultSize = main.Length;
}
```

Where `main` is a class with BYTE* Data and DWORD Length and other functions.
In my CLR:

```
array<Byte>^ Decrypt(array<Byte>^ dataToDecrypt, String^ senderName, String^ receiverName)
{
...
BYTE* resultData = nullptr;
DWORD resultDataSize = 0;
// Call my c++
DecryptFunction(dataToDecryptBytes, dataToDecrypt->Length, sender, receiver, &resultData, &resultDataSize); 

array<Byte>^ result = gcnew array<Byte>(resultDataSize);
for (int i = 0; i < resultDataSize; i++)
{
    result[i] = resultData[i];
}
....
return result;
}
```

In C#:

```
byte[] data = ...;
...
byte[] decrypted = provider.Decrypt(data, "user1", "user2");
...
```

Comment: Try this `array<Byte>^ ary = {0};`

Comment: You are going to have to fix your C++ code first.  Instead of returning a pointer, allow the caller to pass the buffer.  Fixes the very awkward who-owns-the-pointer problem.  And you now can simply pass your managed array with pin_ptr<>.

Comment: Now my code works well (with loop).I can release pointer data after create managed array. 
So you suggest use pin_ptr<>. Can you do a little example for unmanaged -> managed ?

Comment: No, not until you show your C++ code so we can give very specific advice on how to fix it.  With the usual "but I can't change it!" exclamation attached so you'll have to keep what you have.